# Memory leak with gstreamer-1.0 appsrc in imx7 sabre board

Tags: gstreamer, imx7

When i run a sample application of gstreamer-1.0 appsrc example code in x86 machine and imx7 sabre board, i was able to visualize memory leak in the sabre board but not able to visualize the memory leak in x86 machine. Attached code for your reference. Is this a known issue ? Any workarounds/patch available for the memory leak ?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lctmjod1ycwzm85/appsrc_example.zip?dl=0

Comment: Hello Ananth, please share the related part of your code in the question, this way it is more convenient for everybody.

Comment: In the dropbox link, i have shared the code. While using appsrc callback in imx7 the memleak is happening but the memleak is not happening in x86 machine.